# On EC2, detach OS volume, write to a file, then reattach OS volume and boot successfully

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

**Summary of steps that I am attempting:**

- Detach OS volume from Windows_Server_A
- Attach volume to Windows_Server_B
- Modify a harmless file
- Detach from B and reattach at /dev/sda1 for Windows_Server_A
- Boot Successfully

This is not working. The attach / disk management online/offline / detach process is causing the volume to NOT boot when it returns to Server_A

---

** Detailed Steps**

- Detach OS volume from EC2 windows 2012 instance. Let this be Volume_X
- Attach Volume_X to a temporary EC2 windows instance
- In Disk Management of temporary EC2 server, turn new volume online
- Note that there are two partitions. One small one (350MB) without a drive letter and one large one (100GB). The large one gets a drive letter assigned: G
- Navigate to a particular file on G drive
- Modify the file
- Close all windows
- Turn drive offline in Disk Management
- Shut down temporary EC2 server
- Detach Volume_X from temporary server
- Re-Attach Volume_X to its original server at mount point /dev/sda1
- Attempt to boot original server
- The instance never gets past "initialized" and going to Instance Settings - Get Screenshot yields the following:

  [image]

---

**To isolate the problem, I tried without modifying a file:**

- With a fresh, working copy of Volume_X. Detach from Original server. Attach to alternate server.
- All I did was turn the drive "online" and then 2 seconds later turned it "offline" without modifying any data on the drive.
- Reattaching to the original server yields the same exact problem

Thus, it appears that I am corrupting Volume_X by simply attaching it and turning it "online" (disk management) on a separate server.

---

**What is the proper way to move a windows OS volume to another server, for file modification, to then be returned to its original instance and successfully booted from?**

Desired steps:

- Stop original server
- Detach volume
- Attach volume to alternate server
- ????? then modify a file then ?????
- Detach volume from alternate server
- Attach volume to original server
- original server should boot fine

Thanks for your time

Comment: Rampant guesswork: If the volume has a common ancestry (AMIs/Snapshots) with a volume already on instance B, they might have a common identifier in the partition table or on a filesystem that blows the mind of Windows on system B causing it to mark the volume in some way that results in this behavior.  Is this a possibility in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, the disk management utility on windows server 2016 does *something* to the boot partitions (the small ~350MB ones). They simply do not function after going "online" via Server_B's disk management and then "offline". They are no longer bootable on Server_A.

**Since our goal boils down to:**

- Stop Server A
- Move OS volume to Server B as a data volume
- Modify files
- Move OS volume back to Server A and successfully boot

**We can accomplish it as follows:**

- Stop Server_A. Shutdown naturally if possible.
- Detach volume from Server_A
- Attach volume to Linux Server_B. You can spin up a temporary linux instance very quickly if necessary. Ubuntu Server worked well for me.
- `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` - confirm that the read/write NTFS driver is installed. It is often installed by default now.
- Run `fdisk` to find the device name for the partition that you are interested in. We are looking for the identifier for the non-boot partition of the operating system volume (the 100GB partition, not the 350MB partition). Mine was /dev/xvdf2.
- `sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfs_fix` establish a mount point
- `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/xvdf2 /mnt/ntfs_fix` mount the partition as a read/write volume
- Proceed to modify your files. Pico is good for editing text files.
- I changed a registry value by navigating to `/mnt/ntfs_fix/windows/system32/config` and running `chntpw -e SYSTEM`  (to modify a windows system registry value)  [chntpw reg edit docs](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/regedit.txt)
- When you are done making changes, unmount. `sudo umount /dev/xvdf2`
- Detach volume from Server_B
- Attach volume to Server_A as `/dev/sda1` (must be /dev/sda1 for windows ec2 OS volume)
- Start Server_A

**Notes**

- If a forced stop of the OS volume was necessary at the beginning, Then you will receive an error when trying to mount on the linux server. You can use `sudo ntfsfix /dev/xvdf2` to fix the status of the NTFS volume from a "shutdown improperly" state to a "shutdown properly" state. It should then be mountable. Keep in mind that this has the potential to damage your volume, so if you can avoid it by doing a standard shutdown from Server_A, then do it. Otherwise, make sure you have current backups.
- Linux does not read or write from the boot volume (350MB) whereas windows server does something to it. In this way, we are able to modify only the OS-partition of the OS-volume and maintain a bootable volume for when we reattach and boot from Server_A.